# Swift Components.Url is Returning the Wrong URL

Tags: swift, xcode, nsurlcomponents, xcode14

I implemented the following code, where I can pass in the name of the resource and it should give me the URL. I am using Xcode 14 Beta 3.

```
 static let baseUrl = "localhost:8080"
 static func resource(for resourceName: String) -> URL? {
            
            var components = URLComponents()
            components.scheme = "http"
            components.percentEncodedHost = baseUrl
            components.path = "/\(resourceName)"
            return components.url
            
        }
```

I am passing a resource name as 'my-pets' and it is supposed to be returning `http://localhost:8080/my-pets` but it keeps returning `http://my-pets`. I am not sure where I am making a mistake.

Comment: I tested your code in Playgrounds and got `http://localhost:8080/my-pets`

Comment: Thanks! Maybe something to do with Xcode 14 Beta 3.

Comment: `components.url` should return `nil`, since in your case the "host" is syntactically incorrect (see "3.2.2 "Host" in [RFC 3986](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.2.2)). For the scheme "http" a URI is invalid when it does not have a host. So, what URLComponents returns as URL is invalid. You may file a bug. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're passing "localhost:8080" as a hostname. This isn't correct. The hostname is "localhost". 8080 goes in the `port` field.

You may want to use this approach instead:

```
let baseURL = URLComponents(string: "http://localhost:8080")!

func resource(for resourceName: String) -> URL? {
    var components = baseURL
    components.path = "/\(resourceName)"
    return components.url
}
```

You might also do it this way, if the problem is really this simple:

```
let baseURL = URL(string: "http://localhost:8080")!

func resource(for resourceName: String) -> URL? {
    baseURL.appending(path: resourceName)
}
```

Comment: Is this something that recently got changed. Because the same exact code works in Xcode 13 and Xcode 14 Beta 1. But not on Xcode 14 Beta 3.

Comment: I would say yes. I tested your code on Beta3 and reproduced the issue. But I'd say it was a bug in previous versions that Beta3 fixed rather than the other way around.

Comment: IMHO, it's now worse than before. When given a syntactically incorrect host, URLComponents should not produce a URL, especially not a wrong one (a URL with a scheme "http" _requires_ a host). ;)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper I don't know if that really makes sense given the rest of the API. Should a setter with an invalid value set the property (host) to nil or invalidate the entire object (think about what the implementation of that would look like across all properties)? It really kind of points to some awkwardness in the API itself, but "setting an invalid value nils that specific value" is not a wildly incorrect approach in a world before throwing setters.

Comment: Rob, I agree, the usage seems a bit awkward and I wished there is a better API (using a resultBuilder may be). But luckily we discovered this subtlety and we learned again to be careful - as always :)